# Create CRUD web app with Dreamweaver or other framework?

Tags: frameworks, dreamweaver, crud

Background: I have created a CRUD web app using a java based RAD tool called Wavemaker. I am considering developing the app again in a framework that has greater support. Even though I have some experience in development I still get confused by all of the terms. My understanding is that there are languages  (C#, PHP, Javascript, Java, etc), frameworks (Wavemaker, Ruby on Rails, Yii, Symfony, Code Igniter, Zend, etc) and editors (Dreamweaver?)?

I outsourced the development of a mobile version of my web app and this was created using jquery mobile, php and ajax. I started using Dreamweaver because I read it had integration for development with jquery mobile and hence I could perform modifications on my mobile app.

I was wondering whether Dreamweaver was a viable choice for the development of a CRUD web app? I used dreamweaver many years ago for the create of html pages and it would automatically create a lot of "unclean" code that made it hard to maintain. I fear that I would put myself in a similar situation here with server-side code.

If Dreamweaver is not appropriate could you kindly suggest a framework that may meet my requirements?

The main things I liked about Wavemaker:

- Drag and drop widgets
- A lot of the database functions were automatically handled

The main things I don't like about developing with Wavemaker (not Wavemaker itself):

- Support: The support generally involves posting to the forums and hoping for a reply that may never come. I would rather paid support over this option which to be fair is offered by vmware but I found it too confusing.
- Small number of freelance contractors: Much of the functionality within my app required coding or workarounds outside of the standard features of wavemaker and it is very hard to find a freelance wavemaker developer for help
- Ongoing bugs that cause a headache during development

With that being said my priorities are:

- Support: great documentation with rapid response to problems (even if this requires a paid subscription)
- A large number of freelance contractors available (I guess this means a popular framework using a popular language).
- Simple and easy to use (I understand there would be an initial learning curve)
- Stable: I won't be running into bugs that hold up my development and need me to wait for the next release for a fix
- The ability to incorporate reporting like BIRT reports or Jasper.
- Possibly steer clear of Java as I have found Tomcat to be an extra level of complication that it would be great to do without.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dreamweaver was a viable choice for the development of a CRUD web app?

Yes, but with caveats.  It still does not produce code that advanced users would consider "clean" but the integration of JQuery Mobile in CS5.5 makes it a good choice for non-coders or beginning coders who need to spin up rapidly and will worry about elegance later.

That being said, if you are outsourcing the design it is likely that the code you get back will be editable in Dreamweaver but not written in such a way as to take advantage of Dreamweaver's built-in behaviors (automatic code writing).  Dreamweaver expects to see code written to its specs in order to take over for the user.  If not, it is still a great wysiwyg editor and above-average code editor.

But it's not a *framework*.  In your sitution, JQuery Mobile is the framework and any JQuery Mobile developer should be able to step in and run with the project.  But if you write big chunks of the CRUD using Dreamweaver, developers may tell you that they will want to rewrite those sections.  Some won't care.

Comment: Thanks. I found your comments very helpful. You have cleared up a lot of things for me. I appreciate your time.